# How to opt-out of the Windows-Insider Program without having to check the opt-out again? And if I am still asked for new updates?

Tags: windows-10, windows-insider

A while ago, I installed WSL2 and took the seemingly easier installer that is available from the latest Windows Insider Program version in the developer mode.

After installing WSL2, I opted out of the Windows Insider Program again - which is the only way to stop it: waiting until the normal Windows catches up the future version that I have.

I opted out like this:

[image]

Then, just a week later, I agreed on a new installation at shut-down, and I thought that would be just a necessary operational thing going on that you cannot avoid. But I was wrong: the opt-out has just been changed to opt-in again, and I have definitely not done that. It must change back to opt-in as soon as you agree on an update.

Now I would like to be sure that the opt-out stays opt-out, and that I still get only those updates which are needed to keep the system running at all. I do not want to install any new build that prolongs my Insider mode again.

The new update that is now being asked for is `Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version Next (10.0.21301.1010) (KB5000626)`. I have just opted out again, thus I am not sure whether that update is a normal update or an update that prolongs my Insider Program again (and probably opts in again).

Should I just not agree on any update anymore until Windows 10 Insider mode has disappeared?

Is there a better way to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Windows 10, Start, Settings, Update and scroll down to the bottom left.

Then on the Right Side, "Stop Getting Preview Build"  and turn this ON.

Then keep your updates (as you showed above) up to date.

At some point, when a new Production Feature comes out, you will be returned to Production.

This is the best way by far (Insider Releases are working - I have an Insider machine).

If you need to return to production right now, you need to reinstall Windows 10. Not a good idea if you can avoid it.

Comment: OK, my fault. I really have over-read it when I had a second look at it a week later. Normally, I would have expected an "on" to stand for *Yes*, and an "off" to stand for *No*, here it is the other way round (and in addition, the new updates have confused me the most in the end). Thank you for the clear words, and good that I can just install what is on offer - and that Windows plays a fair game here.

Comment: Thanks and good luck with opting out.

Comment: If the user is on a higher build (21301) than what will become 20H1 (approx 20279) Windows will remain in on that build until 20H1 is released.  Since that is indeed the case, they will wait until 20H2 is released, in the second half of 2021. There is no way to go to an earlier build outside of a full install

Comment: @Ramhound Then it is not the very fair Windows game that I thought it would be, as this information should have been given in advance: that agreeing on the Insider program has a ratchet effect that lasts for half a year. I should have used the normal WSL2 installer instead. I just do not like to show every step I do to Windows. On the other hand, I take it as it is, contributing to the development of an OS that so many people use has a small social side. For social media, I use another computer; I could also use the Linux Mint that is on my second drive.

Comment: You were warned exactly what Insider Preview was, I am not exactly sure, how something is unfair when all information is presented before you make a decision.

Comment: The Insider version is working very well so it will not be an issue while waiting.

Comment: @John It is not about waiting or the quality of the OS, but the privacy settings. I have to accept sharing any website that I visit with Microsoft, else I do not get the Insider Program.

Comment: @Ramhound It is now weeks ago, I cannot say for sure how I was warned about this, but I know that after the installation, I thought about the idea of just installing WSL2 and then just going back to the production version, thus, I did not read that information of such a ratchet effect or I had forgotten about it. I took a lot of time to install the Insider Preview, that cannot be the reason why I have overseen it.